Difference between visited = [[False] * M for _ in range(N)] and visited = [[False] * M] * N
What is the difference between visited = [[False] * M for _ in range(N)] and visited = [[False] * M] * N
Based on the visisted list declaration, I got different answers for my solution.
I hope to have an answer on this or refer me to some guides that I can read about it. Thank you.
Here is an online complier:
https://onecompiler.com/python/42bxgzxqv

Can you post the most minimal amount of code where you see a difference in their output?

[False]*M creates a resulting list object with M references to False. Then [...]*N creates another list object with N references to the resulting list object from before. So consider, row = [0]; matrix = [row, row] then do row.append(99), what do you expect from print(row, matrix)?
